# Wkhtmltopdf row alignment off converting HTML table

Tags: html, css, pdf

Using wkhtmltopdf to convert an html table report:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"></html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
      font-family: Plex;
      src: url(/home/shawn/Development/Websites/MDSova/restapi/templates/fonts/IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf);
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: Plex-Bold;
      src: url(/home/shawn/Development/Websites/MDSova/restapi/templates/fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBold.ttf);
    }

    body {
      font-family: Plex, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: #FFF;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .report-data-table,
    .report-title-table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .report-title-table {
      line-height: 36px;
    }

    .report-title-left,
    .title-right {
      width: 15%;
    }

    .report-title-center {
      width: 70%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .report-title-right {
      text-align: right;
    }

    .report-date-header,
    .report-date-col {
      width: 10%;
      background-color: chocolate;
    }

    .report-for-header,
    .report-for-col {
      width: 14%;
      background-color: palegreen
    }

    .test {
      width: 78%;
      background-color: forestgreen;
    }

    .report-date-header,
    .report-for-header,
    .report-source-header,
    .report-sourcename-header,
    .report-account-header,
    .report-method-header,
    .report-reference-header,
    .report-amount-header {
      font-family: Plex-Bold;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="report-title-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="report-title-left">01/15/2023</td>
      <td class="report-title-center">
        <h1>Payment Ledger</h1>
      </td>
      <td class="report-title-right">11:23AM</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="report-data-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="report-date-header">Payment Date</td>
      <td class="report-for-header">Payment For</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

[image]

I understand there is a lot of code here, but the misalignment is several rows down.  it isn't on just one row either - it's random.  Shows fine when the html is thrown in a browser but it doesn't translate to the printed version.
What can I do to get this corrected??  Thanks

Comment: Usually, when creating a PDF additional print CSS can be applied, and that can make it look different from what is shown in the browser. Maybe try to set your columns widths to something more sensible, less controlled. Make the table 100% width, don't set any width on the dark green column, and apply the first 2 column widths in em units so there is enough room to fit the text on one line. Fonts are handled differently so you may need to allow for more space around text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem after adding several more rows, showing that the issue is indeed rather unpredictable.

However, the issue seems to be caused by the `border-collapse: collapse;` css property. Removing this made all rows have the same height.

Of course this also causes white borders to appear around every table cell, which is probably not desired.

To make the borders blend in with the cells a solution is to color the columns using a background pattern for the whole table, instead of a `background-color` property for individual cells.

In the code below I created an inline svg image that consists of three rectangles with the widths and colors of the table columns:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100'>
   <rect width='15%' height='100' fill='chocolate'/>
   <rect x='15%' width='25%' height='100' fill='palegreen'/>
   <rect x='40%' width='60%' height='100' fill='forestgreen'/>
</svg>
```

For the column widths to be calculated properly during the conversion I needed to adjust the dpi setting to 130:

```
wkhtmltopdf --dpi 130 input.html output.pdf
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"></html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: Plex, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: #FFF;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .report-data-table,
    .report-title-table {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .report-title-table {
      line-height: 36px;
    }

    .report-title-left,
    .title-right {
      width: 15%;
    }

    .report-title-center {
      width: 70%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .report-title-right {
      text-align: right;
    }

    .report-date-header,
    .report-date-col {
      width: 15%;
    }

    .report-for-header,
    .report-for-col {
      width: 25%;
    }

    .test {
      width: 60%;
    }
    .svgbackground {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100'><rect width='15%' height='100' fill='chocolate'/><rect x='15%' width='25%' height='100' fill='palegreen'/><rect x='40%' width='60%' height='100' fill='forestgreen'/></svg>");
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="report-title-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="report-title-left">01/15/2023</td>
      <td class="report-title-center">
        <h1>Payment Ledger</h1>
      </td>
      <td class="report-title-right">11:23AM</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class=svgbackground>
  <table class="report-data-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="report-date-header">Payment Date</td>
      <td class="report-for-header">Payment For</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ... many more rows here -->
    <tr class="column-row">
      <td class="report-date-col">01/23/2023</td>
      <td class="report-for-col">PAYMENT ON ACCOUNT</td>
      <td class="test"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Resulting pdf:

[image]

Comment: Above and beyond.  Thanks!!!